# How to set html form elements value using jquery via json object

Tags: jquery, json, forms

I wanna set HTML form elements value using json object by jquery.
I have done adding the values by `serializeArray()` in an HTML localstorage.

```
var formData = $('#page-2').serializeArray();
formData.forEach(function(field){
    var dataDInfo = {};
    if($.inArray(field.name, propertyDList) >= 0){
        if($('#'+field.name).data('displayName')){
            dataDInfo['present'] = field.value;
            dataDInfo[displayName] = $('#'+field.name).data('displayName');
            list.propertyDCategory[field.name] = dataDInfo;
        } else {`enter code here`
            list.propertyDCategory[field.name] = field.value;
        }
    }
});
```

now i am having all values in json object say `list`.
I am getting all data by using

```
var lists = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('list'));

eg: json
{
  aa:ab,
  bb:{
    cc:cb,
    dd:db
  },
  ee:eb
}
```

Now i want to write a edit and update function and fill all the elements value by using json data based on json data field (name of HTML element is equal to json data field) after that i wanna update the local storage list.

Note : html form contain input, radio button, check list, select types of elements.

elements are changing based on select element.

Can anyone help me to write the code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over each json object in your list and then use the key to select your input element using the jquery selector. Use the val method to set the value of the input element.

It will be something like this:

```
for (var key in lists) {   
  $('[name="'+key+'"]').val(lists[key]);
}
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/h4ntduL8/2/)

Comment: please provide an example.

Comment: I provided you with a jsFiddle example

Comment: It is not working for nested JSON data as i have asked in question.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do with nested json data. Please give an example